# Qsub - delaying/staggering job start with a job array

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub

It is possible to delay or stagger the start of jobs launched through a job array with qsub, e.g. `qsub -t1-4 launch.pbs`?

I could do this by a sleeping for a small, but random amount of time in my pbs script, but I wonder whether there is a direct way to specify this to the scheduler through `qsub`

Comment: What scheduler?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218942/how-to-set-the-qsub-to-run-job2-five-seconds-or-any-desired-value-after-the-jo

Comment: That doesn't apply to jobs launched with a job array

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

From http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html :

```
-a date_time
      Available for qsub and qalter only.

      Defines or redefines the time and date at which  a  job
      is   eligible  for  execution.  Date_time  conforms  to
      [[CC]]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS], for  the  details,  please  see
      Date_time in:  sge_types(1).

      If this option is used with qsub or if a  corresponding
      value is specified in qmon then a parameter named a and
      the value in the format CCYYMMDDhhmm.SS will be  passed
      to  the defined JSV instances (see -jsv option below or
      find more information concerning JSV in jsv(1))
```

You can add this option inside your .pbs.

For example,

```
#PBS -a 1550
```

makes the task to wait until 15:50; if it is to late to run at 15:50 today, it will run tomorrow; with

```
#PBS -a 010900
```

the task will run in the morning of the first day of the next month.